# Double decoding Objective C/iPhone

Tags: iphone, encoding

does someone know how i can correctly decode double encoded UTF8 strings? I use the NSXMLParser which decodes it once but after that i'm stuck with a string showing UTF8 encoded characters.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

decode it again using `[NSSting stringWithUTF8String:charPtr];`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how can i get the charPtr correct, because when i use `[@"textwithutf8" cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];` i get NULL back when there are characters like Ã¯ in the string.

Comment: why are you using default encoding as your string is utf8 encoded  so you should use `chPtr =  [str cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Answer (score 0):

What precisely do you mean by "decode double encoded UTF-8 strings"? By a string "showing UTF-8 encoded characters", do you mean [character entity references](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.3), e.g. `&#x6C34` and so on?

If so, there exists a [category](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m) that can help you with this. Specifically, look at `-[NSString stringByDecodingHTMLEntities]`.